# "Symbol's value as variable is void: file-name" when using let

Tags: variables, let-binding

I want to create an Emacs lisp function which

1. composes a path of a diary file which has the format `<some directory>/t<timestamp>.org` and
2. determines whether or not such file exists.

I wrote this:

```lisp
(defun open-diary ()
  (interactive)
  ;; TODO: Find out whether or not file-name exists
  (let ((file-name (format-time-string "/some-dir/diary-files/t%Y%m%d.org"))
        (diary-file-exists (file-exists-p file-name)))
    (message diary-file-exists)))
```

When I run `M-x open-diary` I get the error `Symbol's value as variable is void: file-name`.

How can I fix it, i. e. make sure that `(file-exists-p file-name)` sees the `file-name` variable defined above?

Comment: `let` bindings occur in parallel. You want `let*` instead (or even `when-let`, but lets get this working first :-)

Comment: You should make that into a proper answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lispers read code by indentation, not by counting parens, so your code was hard to read (I fixed that).

Second, `let` binds variables in *parallel*, while `let*` does it *sequentially*
(see [Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html)).

Thus you need to use the latter:

```lisp
(defun open-diary ()
  (interactive)
  ;; TODO: Find out whether or not file-name exists
  (let* ((file-name (format-time-string "/some-dir/diary-files/t%Y%m%d.org"))
         (diary-file-exists (file-exists-p file-name)))
    (message "%s exists? %s" file-name diary-file-exists)))
```